# Sending the failed JSON objects into a file when the post requests fail

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a JSON post request that I am sending to an api for each row in a dataframe. I want to throw the unsuccessful JSON objects into another text file so I can re-process them once the entire dataframe has been looped over completely.

This is the sample code that I have currently for checking different kinds of exceptions:

```
for i in df.index:
        print "This is a JSON object."
        payload='''{"individualInfo":[%s]}''' %(df.loc[i].to_json(orient='columns'))
        print payload

        try:
            r = requests.post(api_url, data=payload, timeout=(0.2,20))
            print r.json()
            print r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print "HTTP Error: %s" %errh
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print "Error Connecting: %s" %errc
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print "Timeout error: %s" %errt
```

I want each payload to be thrown into 2 different files based on whether it got posted successfully or not.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You can write JSON to a file easily with [JSON module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Although writing all of this JSON to files seems a little unnecessary when you already have the data in wherever you are pulling it into the pandas dataframe from. Why not just [log](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) the primary key of the rows that fail?

Comment: So since it is a batch load, I want all the failed JSON to be sent to a file so that if 4 out of 5 records fail, then I can re-process and send the post request to the api for those 4 records again.

Comment: Where is the data coming from that you are posting to the api? Is it in a database? It just seems like storing all of this JSON is redudant and could take up a lot of space depending on how many records you are sending.

Comment: It is just coming from a text file which I am converting to a dataframe and processing it as a JSON. There are not many records as such!